# How to keep the pyplot axis scaled according to one plot only and not extending for other plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I want to plot several functions in one figure, but I want to prevent the axis to be extended if one function is plotted that has much higher/smaller values than others. In the code below, the parameter `alpha` is actually random (here I fixed it to `alpha = 2`), and could get very high values which messes up my plot. Basically what I would like to do is, I'd like to plot one function, then freeze the axis according to its `xlim` and `ylim`, then add the remaining plots without extending the axis anymore if `alpha` happens to be large. How can I do this? [The solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743065/how-to-plot-without-extending-axis-limits) did unfortunately not work for me, i.e., using `plt.autoscale(False)` I would need to fix the limits manually, which is not what I want.

Here is a minimum working example:

```py
x = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi)
data1 = np.sin(0.5*x)
alpha = 2
data2 = alpha*np.sin(x)
data3 = np.sin(x)
data4 = np.sin(x)
data5 = np.cos(x)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(10, 4))
subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2, wspace=0.07)


axsLeft = subfigs[0].subplots(1, 1)
axsLeft.plot(x,data1)
# plt.autoscale(False)
axsLeft.plot(x,data2) #final prediction
axsLeft.plot(x,data3,'--k',linewidth=2.5)
# axsLeft.set_ylim([-1.05,+1.05])
axsLeft.set_xlabel("x")


axsRight = subfigs[1].subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
axsRight[0].plot(data4)
axsRight[1].plot(data5)
axsRight[1].set_xlabel('x')

fig.show()
```

[image: My plot]
This orange plot extends the axis such that the other plots are not interpretable anymore. I'd like the orange plot to to overshoot in the y-direction, like this:
[image: What I want]
but without setting `ylim` manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After plotting the reference, in your case data1, you can retrieve the defined y-axis limits with `get_ylim()` in seperate variables `a` and `b` and rescale your axis accordingly after plotting the remaining curves with `set_ylim`:

This makes sure the axis is always scaled according to the reference and it works even if the lower limit of the y-axis is very low or zero.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi)
data1 = np.sin(0.5*x)
alpha = 2
data2 = alpha*np.sin(x)
data3 = np.sin(x)
data4 = np.sin(x)
data5 = np.cos(x)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(10, 4))
subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2, wspace=0.07)


axsLeft = subfigs[0].subplots(1, 1)
# reference axis
axsLeft.plot(x,data1)
a,b = axsLeft.get_ylim()

axsLeft.plot(x,data2) #final prediction
axsLeft.plot(x,data3,'--k',linewidth=2.5)
axsLeft.set_xlabel("x")

# set limit according to reference
axsLeft.set_ylim((a,b))


axsRight = subfigs[1].subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
axsRight[0].plot(data4)
axsRight[1].plot(data5)
axsRight[1].set_xlabel('x')

fig.show()
```

Comment: This works perfectly, the limits `a` and `b` are now determined by the first plot, and will not change anymore for subsequent plots! Good work around, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust the y-axis to the maximum and minimum values ​​of data1, use the code below. (0.05 is padding.)

```
axsLeft.set_ylim(np.min(data1) - 0.05, np.max(data1) + 0.05)
```

If you want the alpha value to also vary according to data1, you can get the value by subtracting the alpha value from np.max() and np.min(). Below is a modified version of the code you uploaded.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi)
data1 = np.sin(0.5*x)
alpha = np.max(data1) - np.min(data1) # change 1
data2 = alpha*np.sin(x)
data3 = np.sin(x)
data4 = np.sin(x)
data5 = np.cos(x)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(10, 4))
subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2, wspace=0.07)

axsLeft = subfigs[0].subplots(1, 1)
axsLeft.plot(x,data1)
axsLeft.plot(x,data2) #final prediction
axsLeft.plot(x,data3,'--k',linewidth=2.5)
axsLeft.set_xlabel("x")
axsRight = subfigs[1].subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
axsRight[0].plot(data4)
axsRight[1].plot(data5)
axsLeft.set_ylim(-alpha / 2 - 0.05, alpha / 2 + 0.05) # change 2
axsRight[1].set_xlabel('x')

plt.show()
```

Comment: This works for this specific problem, but since `data1` can also change in magnitude, an offset of 0.05 might not always be enough. Therefore I accepted the answer from @Zor Ro because it sets the limits according to the plot and is therefore dynamic.